# Xamarin mtouch linker ProjectDir resolve to Windows not Host

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, agent, xamarin-linker

When using mac agent for building iOS Xamarin project from Visual Studio on Windows custom linker path used in -B ${ProjectDir} is resolving ProjectDir to Windows instead of Host location.

The only workaround is to specify the path by hand but it's very inconvenient.

It seems that the same issue is reported on Xamarin Bugzilla but it appears that is not resolved or was reintroduced with one of the latest Xamarin tools version:
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=22906#c4

Do you know if there is another workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Issue was fixed in Visual Studio version 15.4.